# How to put a break in an email variable?

Tags: php, variables, break, mail-form

So I'm working on a mail form for my site and I got i working. Now I want to personalise it with a cutsom message but... I have no idea how to put line breaks in the variable message. I tried using `<br />`but that just prints it out as a word. So any idea's?

P.S. I may be totally wrong feel free to totally change what is in the message I just want to understand the concept.

```
<?php
$message =
"You recieved mail from  $mail with a question." . 
"The question contains the following:" . 
"$_POST['message'];";
?>
```

EDIT:
@Ben Pearl Kahan answer worked for me! Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Assuming you are sending plain text mail line breaks would be ok, either as multiline message or added manually i.e. `"\r\n"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In double quotes, `\r\n` will be a new line.

Example:

```
<?php
    $message =
    "You recieved mail from  $mail with a question.\r\n" . 
    "The question contains the following:\r\n" . 
    $_POST['message'];
?>
```

FYI, `"$_POST['message']"` is not correct concatenation; you should either process the array variable *outside* the string:

```
"text ".$_POST["message"]." more text"
```

or use curly brackets (NB: this will only work if your string is enclosed in *double quotes*):

```
"text {$_POST["message"]} more text"
```

Comment: I just double-checked and I don't believe it does... Where is the syntax error?

Comment: You are right ... I expected that the quotes inside quotes throw an error. You always learn something new.

Comment: Happy to help you both!

Comment: @JessieDenRidder Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it worked for you!

Comment: I just did. I was trying to do that but you have to wait a couple of minutes :P

Answer (score 0):

For linebreaks, PHP as "\n" [(see double quote strings)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) and PHP_EOL.

```
<?php
$message = "You recieved mail from $mail with a question\nThe question contains the following:\n{$_POST['message']}";
?>
```